# Add all the previous numbers in a for loop to get the current number

Tags: php, for-loop

I have this for loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {

    echo $i . "<br>";

}
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Now what I want is to add all the previous numbers on each loop. So the output should be:

```
1
2 // add all above to get this number
3 // add all above to get this number
6 // add all above to get this number
12 // add all above to get this number
24 // add all above to get this number
48 // add all above to get this number
96 // add all above to get this number
...etc
```

**The first and second number doesn't necessarily have to be in the loop, that can be defined manually outside.**

**What I don't want is** to add the value of $i on each loop, but to add all the previous numbers on each loop.

I have tried summing up using this code:

```
$sum = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    $sum = $sum + $i;
    echo $sum . "<br>";

}
```

But I get this output:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Your logic is flawed at the beginning. How is sum of '1' is '2' ?

Comment: Not sure how you get those numbers in the desired output. Can you explain in math how you get those numbers?

Comment: The first two numbers can be defined manually outside the loop as well. No issues with me. I'll edit that out.

Comment: Voted to close for unclear question

Comment: you want every loop to generate a result which is the sum of the previous results. Problem is that, problem is that you have to start with a base number, cause the first iteration won't have any previous results to sum. You should make put an if in which you generate "manually" the results for the first tow iterations

Comment: It's worth noting that `$i` doesn't actually play a role in this sequence; you could actually calculate this with a `while(true)` loop. If the actual sequence you need involves substituting something for `$i`, such as the entries from an array, then you have gone wrong somewhere in defining the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$results = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++){
    $currentResult = 0;
    if ($i < 2){
        $currentResult = $i+1;
    }
    else{
        foreach($results as $currenNumber){
            $currentResult += $currenNumber;
        }
    }
    echo $currentResult . '<br>';
    $results[] = $currentResult;
}
?>
```

Comment: This works great, but lets say I have a php array (1,2,3,4,5), can I do the same with it?

Comment: @MarwanAnsari If that is what you want to do, then you've asked the wrong question. You specifically gave us a for loop, and a sample output, so that is what people have shown you how to create. Iterating through an array will result in different code, and different output.

Comment: @IMSoP I realized that for loop wouldn't work for what I wanted. So decided to ask that in a different way. Do you know how to achieve what I want or it's better to just ask a different question?

Comment: @MarwanAnsari I don't really understand what you want. I think in trying to ask a simplified question (which is a good idea) you've simplified too far, and lost sight of the goal. If you kept asking variations of the question, all we could do is keep guessing what you really want, which is a waste of our time and yours. I suggest asking a new question, but spending some time planning it first, to make sure you've come up with a version that actually relates to your original problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$value = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    if($value < 3){
        $value = $value + 1;
    } else{
        $value = $value * 2;
    }
    echo $value . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Can be written shorter by using     $value += 1 and     $value *= 2;

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately, it's not multiplied by 2, but add all the previous numbers.

Comment: what you want Is the same as this but with 4 instead of 3 in the "if($value < 3){" line

Comment: @MarwanAnsari It will always come to the same thing once the pattern is established: n[x] is the sum of all (n[1], n[2] ... n[x-1]), and n[x+1] is that same sum, plus n[x]; we can save recalculating the first part of the sum because we already know it adds up to n[x], so we have n[x+1] = n[x] + n[x], or n[x+1] = n[x]×2.